# RegionPlot is slow to plot a simple region

Tags: plotting, regions, options

I start out with 5x5 matrix `gCorrMatrix[g]` depending on a parameter $g$ and an unknown $W_2$

```
gCorrMatrix[g_] := {{1, 0, Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g)}, 
       {0, Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 0}, 
       {Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 0, 
         -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/g^2)}, 
       {0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
      0, -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/
              g^2), 0}, {-((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 0, 
         -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/g^2), 0, 
         -((-1 - 2*g + Subscript[W, 2] + 4*g*Subscript[W, 2] - 
           g^2*Subscript[W, 2]^2)/g^3)}}
```

I define a function of this matrix that returns an inequality

```
gRegion[g_] := Reduce[Eigenvalues[gCorrMatrix[g]] >= 0, Subscript[W, 2]]
```

that gives a range of values of $W_2$ for each $g$ where `gCorrMatrix[g]` is positive-definite. Evaluating gives

```
In[157]:= Timing[gRegion[.3]]

During evaluation of In[157]:= Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

Out[157]= {0.083676, 0.703257 <= Subscript[W, 2] <= 0.714234}
```

Clearly this is computationally expensive to evaluate over and over again. Mathematica just hangs when I try to plot

```
RegionPlot[gRegion[g], {g, -1/8, .5}, {Subscript[W, 2], .5, 2}]
```

This surprised me because `gRegion[g]` is very simple (just a line segment and independent of $g$). Is there a way I can tell `RegionPlot` to just plot each line segment of $W_2$ sequentially? This really shouldn't take more than a few seconds. I thought I could change this with the `Method` option but I can't see anything in the documentation aside from `Method->"Automatic"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine your matrix to explicitly depend on the values of $g$ and $W_2$ (and, while you're at it, lose the `Subscript` expressions that make everything a bit more complicated):

```
ClearAll[gCorrMatrix]
gCorrMatrix[g_, w_] := 
  {
    {1, 0,w, 0, -((-1 + w)/g)}, 
    {0, w, 0, -((-1 + w)/g), 0}, 
    {w, 0, -((-1 + w)/g), 0, -((1 - w - 2*g*w)/g^2)}, 
    {0, -((-1 + w)/g), 0, -((1 - w - 2*g*w)/g^2), 0},
    {-((-1 + w)/g), 0, -((1 - w - 2*g*w)/g^2), 0, -((-1 - 2*g + w + 4*g*w - g^2*w^2)/g^3)}
  }
```

Then create a predicate function that checks whether the matrix above is positive definite when given *numerical values* of the two parameters $g$ and $W_2$:

```
ClearAll[gPosQ]
gPosQ[g_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ] := 
  PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[gCorrMatrix[g, w]]
```

You can then use that function as a predicate in `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[
  gPosQ[g, w],
  {g, -1/8, 0.5}, {w, 0.5, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 8
]
```

[image: 2D regions in which the matrix of interest is positive definite]

Adjust the values of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` to attain your preferred plotting goals.

Comment: Nice trick using `?_NumericQ` to prevent any symbolic manipulation. One comment—the region in the neighborhood of $g\approx 1/2$ has vanishing measure and hence isn't shown by `RegionPlot`. This isn't a defect—it's in the documentation—but it is a limitation of this type of analysis. As I increase the size of the correlation matrix (computed before) and improve the bound, `RegionPlot` sees less and less of the graph. It's still very good for visualizing the uncertainty in $W_2$, but extracting the solution function $W_2(g)$ needs a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

```
Clear[gCorrMatrix, sol, lowsol, upsol]; 
gCorrMatrix[
  g_] = {{1, 0, Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g)}, {0, 
    Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
    0}, {Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
    0, -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/
       g^2)}, {0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
    0, -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/g^2), 
    0}, {-((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
    0, -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/g^2), 
    0, -((-1 - 2*g + Subscript[W, 2] + 4*g*Subscript[W, 2] - 
         g^2*Subscript[W, 2]^2)/g^3)}} /. Subscript[W, 2] -> w2;
sol[g_] := 
  Reduce[Eigenvalues[gCorrMatrix[Rationalize[g, 0]]] >= 0, w2];
lowsol[g_] := sol[g][[1]];
upsol[g_] := sol[g][[-1]];
Plot[{lowsol[g], upsol[g]}, {g, 0, 5}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Red}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
Plot[{lowsol[g], upsol[g]}, {g, -.1, -0.005}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Cyan}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- When `g` is fixed,since this is one dimensional plot,we can use `NumberLinePlot` instead.

```
gCorrMatrix[
   g_] = {{1, 0, Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g)}, {0,
      Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
     0}, {Subscript[W, 2], 0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
     0, -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/
        g^2)}, {0, -((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
     0, -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/g^2), 
     0}, {-((-1 + Subscript[W, 2])/g), 
     0, -((1 - Subscript[W, 2] - 2*g*Subscript[W, 2])/g^2), 
     0, -((-1 - 2*g + Subscript[W, 2] + 4*g*Subscript[W, 2] - 
          g^2*Subscript[W, 2]^2)/g^3)}} /. Subscript[W, 2] -> w2;
plot[g_] := 
 NumberLinePlot[
  Reduce[Eigenvalues[gCorrMatrix[Rationalize[g, 0]]] >= 0, w2], w2]
plot[.3]
plot[-.001]
```

[image]

[image]

- To draw the region

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
   Eigenvalues[gCorrMatrix[g]] >= 0 // Thread, {g, w2}];
RegionPlot[RegionMember[region, {g, w2}], {g, -.2, .5}, {w2, .5, 8}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> 5, MeshStyle -> Red]
RegionPlot[
 And @@ Thread[
   Eigenvalues[gCorrMatrix[g]] >= 0], {g, -.2, .5}, {w2, .5, 8}]
```

[image]

```
solve[g_] := 
  Reduce[Eigenvalues[gCorrMatrix[Rationalize[g, 0]]] >= 0, w2];
reg[g_] := RegionProduct[Point[{{g}}], ImplicitRegion[solve[g], {w2}]];

right = RegionUnion[Table[reg[g], {g, .01, .5, .005}]] // Region
left = RegionUnion[Table[reg[g], {g, -.1, -.01, .005}]] // Region
Show[left, right, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True]
```

[image]